# Create generic set function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Honestly, I had a bit of a hard time to define a proper title for this question.

I want to write a function that I can pass an Interface as a Generic and a string as a parameter which is a Key of that Interface. This returns a function that can receive a single parameter that should be properly typed (Interface[Key]).

```js
export const createFunction = <T extends Record<string, any>>(
  key: keyof T,
): (value: ?????) => void => (value) => {
  // Do something with value
};
```

I tried playing around with a function type but wasn't able to make it work

```js
type Getter<T extends Record<string, any>> = <Key extends keyof T>(
  key: Key,
) => (value: T[Key]) => void;
```

Comment: I suggest reading about [functional lenses](https://apiumhub.com/tech-blog-barcelona/functional-lenses-javascript/) which implement the behaviour you want. It's a generic and reusable way to get/set properties that is divorced from a concrete object. You can also get ready made implementations for example Ramda implements [`view()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#view) and [`set()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#set) which take a lense and do get/set from a further supplied object. The documentation shows how to create different kinds of lenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question - is this what you're after?

```js
export const createSetterFactory = <T extends Record<string, any>>() => {
  return <K extends keyof T>(key: K) => (value: T[K]) => {
    // Do something with value
  }
};

interface MyInterface {
  foo: number;
}

// pass Interface as a Generic
const mySetterFactory = createSetterFactory<MyInterface>();

// a string as a parameter which is a Key of that Interface
const fooSetter = mySetterFactory('foo');

// Do something with the value of foo
fooSetter(123);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton, mate. Why didn't I think of using a factory pattern :)